# AngularJS $routeParam vs $location.search(a,b) difference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

Setting a URL parameter via $routeParams, or setting it using $location.search() as a setter seem to achieve the same thing, other than how the parameter appears in the URL, and where in the app it is set.

From app.js config...

```
$routeProvider
   .when('/myRoute/:myParam', {});
```

vs.

From a controller...

```
$scope.setLocationParam = function (name, param) {
    $location.search(name, param);
};
```

I have a simple ajax app where I'm going step-by-step through a few pages and I want to maintain state in the URL so that each subsequent route is calling an api based on URL params set from the previous route.

When would one want choose one method over the other?

I'm leaning towards a search param via $location because it's more descriptive but I thought I'd ask you fine people!s

Comment: The first example configures a route, the second changes the current URL. What do you mean by _"choose one method over the other"_?

Comment: Essentially I can set a param either way, and then read it later. For my case it is probably more appropriate to set a query param vs. configuring a route.

Comment: I still don't understand. The first example doesn't set a parameter.

Comment: somewhat boils down to whether you want pretty url's or not